# Laravel's 5.5 authentication bouncing back

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm following a tutorial for login.

I wrote all the code step by step but at the end I am not able to log in, even when I provide the correct credentials.

Below is my code:

LoginController

```
public function getLogin()
{
    if (Auth::guard('web')->check())
    {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    return view('login');
}
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{

    $auth = Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['username'=>$request->username,
        'password'=>$request->password,'active'=> 1]);
    if($auth)
    {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
    return redirect()->back()->with(['error' =>'Wrong Credentials']);


}

public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();
    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```

DashboardController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
public function dashboard()
{
    return view('layouts.app');
}code here
```

Middleware (VisitorsMiddleware.php)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'web')
{
   if(!Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
       return redirect()->route('dashboard');
   }
   return $next($request);
}
```

CheckRole.php

```
epublic function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $roles  = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());
    if($request->user()->hasRole($roles)|| !$roles)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->route('/noPermission');
}
private function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
{
    $actions = $route->getAction();
    return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles']: null;
}
```

web.php

```
 Route::group(['middleware'=>['visitors','roles']],function (){
 Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogout']);
 Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@dashboard']);});

Route::get('/', ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin']);
```

Comment: How do you test, what is your errors, be more specific.

Comment: I don't get any error when i try to login. But the required page I want the login to go does not open. When i click on the login button, it doesn't route to the dashboard. Also when type the url for instance `/dashboard` it still redirect to the login page

Comment: Also I tried to get the name of the user with this `{{Auth::user()->name}}` it give error of "calling a non-object". I think something is wrong which I don't know. Is there a way to call `Auth` because i am thinking the system is not identifying `Auth`

Comment: Can you debug on the server side? if not write some kind of debug output so you can see what is happening.